# can graphicsmagick import (screenshot) several snaps per second?

Tags: linux, screenshot, graphicsmagick

I've read in the http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-snaps that it can produce several screenshots in a row, eventually with a desired pause time inbetween.
However it seems that either I don't understand how to use it or it can't even do several screenshots with 1 second delay.
The command I tried is:
gm import -snaps 10 -pause 1  -window root ./"screenshot-$(date +%d_%m_%Y-%H:%M:%S).png"

But this above command other than waiting 10 seconds and producing 1 screenshot with the initial screen it does not do what I read it should.

So, can gm import do several screenshots with a delay ? if so can it do more than 1 screenshot in a second ?

Comment: I'm guessing that the filename is evaluated **once** at the start and therefore gives the same filename for each grab and overwrites the previous. So I guess your file will be named according to the start-time of your first grab but will have the contents of the last grab. I would try a filename more like `grab-%02d.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell nope, tried this: gm import -snaps 3 -pause 1  -window root "screenshot_%02d.png" and the same, also the picture it takes is the one in the first second, I know this because I opened various file managers while waiting for the 10 snaps to happen and none of those other windows appeared in the saved screenshot . So it must really be the first grab...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use GIF format to capture an animated GIF:

```
gm import -snaps 3 -pause 1 -window root screenshot.gif
```

Or use this to capture a series of images with sequential numbering padded to 2 digits as a result of the `%02d` in the filename:

```
gm import -snaps 3 -pause 1 -window root +adjoin screenshot_%02d.png
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems I really have to be more patient reading the man page...

Answer (score 0):

Try authorizing the command with the "loop" utility

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what is the loop utility ?